# Postgis spatial query st_disjoint

Tags: postgis, layers, query

I have 2 layers that I want to compare. I wish to retrieve the features in the layer 1 that have no part in common with the features in the layer 2. I try queries like that but do not returns me the expected result :

```
select * from c1 join activite.c2 
on st_disjoint(c1.geom, c2.geom) 
WHERE c2 blabla' ;
```

I get here (except error) a table that lists for each feature in the layer 1 those of layer 2 who do not cut it. But how to recover those of layer 1 which are intersected by any of the layer 2 ? Hope it s clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer with a count & group by:

```
select c.gid, c.*, count(c.gid) from c1 
join c2
on st_disjoint(c1.geom, c2.geom)
WHERE c2.nom_comm ILIKE 'blabla'
GROUP BY c.gid
having count(c.gid) >22 ;
```

> 22 means disjoint with all features of c2.

Comment: be aware that st_disjoint **does not** use spatial indexes.